# Sequelize WHERE force one condition or not depending on a programmatically condition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a bool field in my DB and an endpoint to query that model.
The user sends the bool field `is_social_field`, if the value is `true`, I need to force to query only true values, otherwise return it if is true or false.

I managed to do with an OR condition, but I would like to have another solution, this does not seem the best practise. 
What do you guys think?

```
const { is_social_field } = req.body;

...

where{
  [Op.or]: [{is_social: true}, {is_social: is_social_field}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the query object using the ternary operator like this:

```
const whereClause = req.body.is_social_field ? {is_sovial:true}:{};
```

And then use it with spread operator like this in the where clause:

```
where :
{
    ...whereClause
}
```

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { is_social_field } = req.body;
```

Now you can use the is_social_field to construct the db query. We have 2 scenario's to take care of here.
**1.** When we need all results irrespective of `is_social_field`. An appropriate query for that would be without the `is_social` field.
Like `where = {}`

**2.** When we need to filter results based on `is_social_field`. That query would be `where = {is_social: is_social_field}`

These two can be achieved via a ternary operator as pointed out in [@khopadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850704/3324509)'s answer

You can also extend object assignment to get rid of the ternary operator too like

```js
const where = {...is_social_field && {is_social:true}}
```